# Create a path in certain order for points while keeping layer attributes

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, spatial

I have a very large data set with 5 columns, as sampled below:

```
one_truck <- data.frame(readdate = as.POSIXct(c("2019-02-04 12:36:17", 
                                                "2019-02-04 12:37:17",
                                                "2019-02-04 12:38:17",
                                                "2019-02-04 12:39:17",
                                                "2019-02-04 12:40:17",
                                                "2019-02-04 12:41:04")),
                        y = c(43.33329, 43.33329, 43.33403,
                              43.33329, 43.33310, 43.33333),
                        x = c(-80.43819, -80.43824,-80.43875,
                              -80.43907, -80.43968, -80.44051),
                        speed = c(0, 0, 5, 4, 4, 6),
                        id = c("169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab",
                                    "169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab",
                                    "169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab",
                                    "169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab",
                                    "169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab",
                                    "169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab"))

one_truck_sf <- st_as_sf(one_truck, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
```

I want to create a line between each point and the next one, following the order of the `readdate` column while keeping the value of speed. I am not sure if there is a function able to do it correctly maybe on sf or other packages like that. But for now I have been trying to use `st_cast` or `st_combine` with unsuccessful results.
I have done the following as a test thinking in using some of the apply functions to process the whole 2000 points:

```
test <- st_combine(one_truck_sf[1:2,]) %>% st_cast()
```

But it returns a list with only the geometric values, so I loose the speed attribute.

I have also tried

```
test <- st_cast(one_truck_sf, "LINESTRING")
```

But that just seems to convert one point into an non existing line (because I am missing one point)

What am I missing? I think this process should be very common but haven't found any package that does it or any questions previously asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can augment the previous x and y to the dataframe (you will lose the first record for each group - based on id), then you can create a linestring object based on previous x, y and record x, y. Here is how I have done it:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

one_truck_next <- one_truck %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(readdate, .by_group = T) %>% 
     mutate(prev_y = lag(y),
            prev_x = lag(x)) %>% drop_na() # drop first record that does not have any previous value

one_truck_next
## A tibble: 5 × 7
## Groups:   id [1]
#  readdate                y     x speed id                             #prev_y prev_x
#  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                           <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2019-02-04 12:37:17  43.3 -80.4     0 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4
#2 2019-02-04 12:38:17  43.3 -80.4     5 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4
#3 2019-02-04 12:39:17  43.3 -80.4     4 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4
#4 2019-02-04 12:40:17  43.3 -80.4     4 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4
#5 2019-02-04 12:41:04  43.3 -80.4     6 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4

# create a line string based on previous and record x,y values (latitude, longitude)
one_truck_next$geom = sprintf("SRID=4326;LINESTRING(%s %s, %s %s)", one_truck_next$prev_y, one_truck_next$prev_x, one_truck_next$y, one_truck_next$x)
one_truck_next = st_as_sf(one_truck_next, wkt="geom")

one_truck_next
## A tibble: 5 × 8
## Groups:   id [1]
#   readdate                y     x speed id                             prev_y prev_x                                     geom
#  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                           <dbl>  <dbl>                         <LINESTRING [°]>
#1 2019-02-04 12:37:17  43.3 -80.4     0 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4 (43.33329 -80.43819, 43.33329 -80.43824)
#2 2019-02-04 12:38:17  43.3 -80.4     5 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4 (43.33329 -80.43824, 43.33403 -80.43875)
#3 2019-02-04 12:39:17  43.3 -80.4     4 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4 (43.33403 -80.43875, 43.33329 -80.43907)
#4 2019-02-04 12:40:17  43.3 -80.4     4 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4  (43.33329 -80.43907, 43.3331 -80.43968)
#5 2019-02-04 12:41:04  43.3 -80.4     6 169c84e31cfa40e5bb8ccff60ddaab   43.3  -80.4  (43.3331 -80.43968, 43.33333 -80.44051)
```